# Razor TagHelpers default registration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-2

Should I expect any TagHelpers to be automatically registered for use in my Razor Pages?

That is, if I don't write `addTagHelper *, whatever` *anywhere*, should I expect any TagHelpers to be registered?

I'm seeing inconsistent behaviour between projects and I cant work out why.

In neither project do I have the line `addTagHelper`, but in one project a TagHelper from the web-project assembly is automatically registered and operating on tags in my view (my desired behaviour, actually), but in the other project the same* setup does not auto-register a tag helper

- somethings different, im sure. but i cant find it.

Comment: The `addTagHelper` line must be added to the view or `_ViewImports.cshtml` to apply to all views. Without that, your tag helpers will not be available.

Comment: these were my thoughts. But i definitely dont have anything anywhere!